# EmberFire & Firebase Storage Reference

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire, firebase-storage

I'm relatively new to Ember and EmberFire. I'm working on a Client/Logo management application. I've currently got Firebase Authentication and Firebase data working as expected. When I go to upload the logo to Firebase storage, I am presented with this error:

```
Uncaught Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp(). firebase.js:30
```

Here is the action that is being called:

**Controller**

```js
firebase: Ember.inject.service( 'firebase' ),
actions: {
    createClient(){
        let name = this.get( 'clientName' );
        let image = document.getElementById( 'client-image' );
        let storeName = name.replace( / /g, '' );

        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

        let file = image.files[0];
        let metadata = {
            'contentType' : file.type
        };

        let uploadTask = storageRef.child( `uploads/${storeName}/${file.name}` ).put( file, metadata );

        uploadTask.on( 'state_changed', null, function( error ){
            console.error( 'Upload Failed:', error );
        }, function(){
            console.log( 'Uploaded', uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.' );
            console.log( uploadTask.snapshot.metadata );
            let uploadUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
            console.log( 'File available at ', url );

            let client = this.store.createRecord( 'client', {
                name: name,
                image: uploadUrl,
                isActive: false,
                timestamp: new Date().getTime()
            } );
            client.save();

        } );

        // Tell the route to hide the client form.
        this.send( 'hideAddClientForm' );
    }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div id="new-overlay" class="overlay" {{action "hideAddClientForm"}}></div>
<div id="newClient">
    {{input type="text" id="client-name" placeholder="Client Name" value=clientName}}<br />
    {{input type="file" id="client-image" value=clientImage}}
    <div class="submitBtn" {{action "createClient"}}>Add Client</div>
</div>
```

So, in short, how do I access the Firebase reference provided by EmberFire so that I can invoke the "storage()" method to it that is shown [here in the Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/storage/index.html). If access to that reference isn't possible, do I have to create another, "non-EmberFire" reference to Firebase in order to use Storage? I'm simply trying to uploading a .jpg.

Comment: I will add that I have also tried `firebase.initializeApp()`, which ends up saying `Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.`As I've said, Authentication and Database stuff is working fine, it's just the File Storage that's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you are using [EmberFire 2.0](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/releases/tag/v2.0.0). You can access the Firebase Storage API through the `firebaseApp` service:

```
firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),
actions: {
  doSomething() {
    const storageRef = this.get('firebaseApp').storage();
  }
}
```

The `firebaseApp` service is an already initialized app, not to be confused with the `firebase` service, which is the database reference only (kept for backwards compatibility).